# Ghost blog down after a few hours

Tags: nginx, ubuntu-14.04, digital-ocean, ghost-blog

Ok, so I have a droplet at Digital Ocean with Ubuntu with 2 Ghost blogs under a Nginx instance.

One is hosted at gabsferreira.com and other at panddi.com.

For some reason, gabsferreira.com goes down after a few hours online, giving me this error:

```
502 Bad Gateway

nginx/1.4.6 (Ubuntu)
```

If I look at the Nginx log, I got multiple lines of something like this:

```
2017/05/01 23:46:18 [error] 928#0: *14500 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 66.249.79.174, server: gabsferreira.com, request: "GET /robots.txt HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:2368/robots.txt", host: "gabsferreira.com"
2017/05/01 23:47:06 [error] 928#0: *14502 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 177.74.125.151, server: gabsferreira.com, request: "GET /criando-e-enviando-arquivos-para-seu-repositorio-no-github/ HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:2368/criando-e-enviando-arquivos-para-seu-repositorio-no-github/", host: "gabsferreira.com", referrer: "https://www.google.com.br/"
2017/05/01 23:47:07 [error] 928#0: *14502 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 177.74.125.151, server: gabsferreira.com, request: "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:2368/favicon.ico", host: "gabsferreira.com", referrer: "http://gabsferreira.com/criando-e-enviando-arquivos-para-seu-repositorio-no-github/"
```

If I restart the machine, it starts working again, but goes down after a few hours.

During all this, the other blog keeps online and ok, so Nginx and Ghost are running.

Inside my sites-enabled folder for Nginx I got two configs for each blog, panddi.conf:

```
server {
    server_name blog.panddi.com www.blog.panddi.com;

    root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    index index.html index.htm;

    client_max_body_size 10G;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:2777;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_buffering off;
    }
}
```

And gabs.conf:

```
server {
    #listen 80 default_server;
    #listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;

    #listen 127.0.0.1:2368;

    server_name gabsferreira.com;

    root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    index index.html index.htm;

    client_max_body_size 10G;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:2368;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_buffering off;
    }
}
```

I have no idea what's going on and why it stays online only for a few hours.

Thanks.

Comment: Did you manage to solve this? It started happening out of the blue and restarting the server doesnt help.

Comment: @Brian it looks like the problem was that I was running two blogs in the same droplet and it was running out of memory. I separated them in 2 different droplets and it seems ok now.

Comment: Can you please add the log file from ghost? There must be more information why ghost is crashing